Proper Use of CPCV for Hyperparameter Tuning and Backtesting in a Trading Strategy
I'm working on a binary classification model for a month-end trading strategy with 6 months of data. Initially, I split the data by using the last month for evaluation and backtesting, but this left me with only one month for evaluation, which i feel isn't sufficient.
To address this, I decided to use Combinatorial Purged Cross-Validation, which provides 15 different splits and 5 different paths for hyperparameter tuning and backtesting.
I used CPCV with 15 splits to determine the optimal hyperparameters.
After tuning, I trained the final model on the entire dataset using these hyperparameters.
For backtesting, I'm considering using these CPCV-tuned hyperparameters on the same 15 splits.

Concerns:

When tuning hyperparameters, am i supposed to maximize the average
evaluation metric across all 15 splits, or should I focus on the
average of the 5 different paths?
If I use the obtained best parameters within the same 15 splits for
backtesting, am I introducing information leakage?

I feel like I might be
misinterpreting CPCV. Could someone clarify the correct approach for
both hyperparameter tuning and backtesting to avoid information
leakage?
Thank you!

Could someone please shed some light on my questions?
What I essentially want to understand is whether Combinatorial Purged Cross-Validation allows for the use of the entire dataset for hyperparameter tuning and backtesting, without needing a separate holdout set that is never used during training. If so, isn't it introducing information leakage?
